# Android Studio: Always highlight currently opened file left sidebar

Tags: android, android-studio

I find it that sometimes the file highlighted in left sidebar is not exactly the file that I'm currently viewing, is there a setting that would always highlight the currently viewing file.

In the screenshot below, I'm viewing the `TagLayoutViewModel` but the highlight on left sidebar is on `ImagePagerViewModel`

[image: Supporting image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, found it. Was pretty easy. Just toggled the setting `Always Select Opened File` in the sidebar as shown in image.
[image: Supporting image]